# How can a glass rod become charged if it is an insulator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, insulators

I was reading some of the other questions, and I found this one about a glass rod and how it gains a net charge when rubbed with a silk scarf. I learned from working in a shop one summer that most solids are insulators, because their electrons are tightly bound, so it is hard to knock them off. Why would such a simple motion (like a moving scarf) knock electrons from an insulator (I looked it up and glass is an insulator)?

Comment: The energy to ionize an atom in a solid is a few eV, which is a very small amount of energy: 1.60217657 × 10-19J. When we rub a rod with a scarf, we expend work on the order of 1-100J, so that's, at least 6-8 orders of magnitude more energy than is actually needed to ionize the number of atoms that lead to a macroscopic charge on the rod, which is probably around 1e-6Coulomb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conductivity is not just about how tightly bound electrons are, but equally about how easy it is for them to travel.

Example: a bunch of islands in a shark-infested sea. You cannot swim from one island to the next although it is close. At low tide you can walk across no problem. The first example is an insulator, the second is a conductor.

Rubbing (google triboelectricity) causes unlike atoms to stick and unstick frequently. Atoms "fight" over electrons, and the stronger one gets to take the electron home. It is like air lifting them from the island - shark infested waters or not.

There are lists of materials (the triboelectric series) that tell you which material will give up its electrons when in contact with another material. Glass is high on the list - it loses electrons easily. The can't move sideway, but they can be picked off the surface.

Comment: Did you make that analogy up? If so, you should be a teacher. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

An informal definition of insulator is that electrons are bounded enough so that they cannot flow all over the material, they remain next to the atom where they belong. In a conductor electrons can move freely and flow to different parts of the solid, detached from the original atoms. Why that happens depends on many factors, but it does not mean that you cannot knock an electron off the surface of an insulator if you apply enough force. Specially on the surface, where the atoms are not surrounded all over by other atoms. In some materials the energy needed to knock out a surface electron is not that high.

Comment: Good start to an answer. Note that insulators can carry both positive and negative charge... it depends on what they interact with. When you rub two unequal insulators, electrons will be transfered - one becomes positive, the other becomes negative.

Comment: Thanks, I restricted the answer to  the case of removing the electrons because it was directly related with the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms.Elect is inverse mag.Hold powerful magnets on opposite sides of a thin glass window.Report findings.Next q.v.fiber optics.Photons being electro messenger particles. The longer and thinner the glass rod,the greater charge on surface possible. A magnetic field does not transmit through fiber optic thread. Good thing.
  Glass (silica) is a liquid not solid. It is not used as an insulator. Add lead for a solid crystal molecular formation. Cheap but not for heavy loss in power lines.Ceramics are economical.Yettrlium ceramic composites are best at high temps but too expensive. On the other hand when supercooled these ceramics are super conducted for CERN magnets. 
  Hope that helps.
  Now, on a brief history of the search and discovery of practical insulators; q.v." Mover of Men and Mountains " by R.G. LA Tourneau. 
  Or you will find the origins of Planck's quanta, and even string theory in Oliver Heaviside's statements on pgs.254-254 "Pioneers of Electrical Communication."
 Or if you are familiar with more advanced works...q.v."Electromagnetic Theory" by Heaviside; vol.I.pgs.444-446.